# How to find a suitable blockchain talent?

Tags: web-development, design, group-freelancing, clients, project

A new project I am working on needs a blockchain full stack developer and designer.They must understand solidity (Ethereum), sidechains (Bitcoin), etc. Anyone interested?
In addition, I feel that it's quite difficult to find talent in this industry. Do you know how to find a good candidate in the blockchain field?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are looking for. It is not difficult like you said. Blockchain is the hottest skill right now, it opened a huge market. Many people join and develop it to become talents. You can find them in some blockchain or crypto forums, it is a talent pool.

Comment: I believed that I have a potential project. I think I need to find some platforms like Upwork or Fiverr but that focus on providing blockchain freelancer. Btw, this is the first time I post a question and I don't expect to get an answer this quickly. Thank for your comment.

Comment: Haha, you're welcome !